# Mixed effects model with negative variances

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I know this is a kinda old question, but I just wonder if this has a solution now.

I usually perform the mixed effects model with `lme4` package with `lmer` function. However, I know this function does not allow me to include the negative variance components in the model.

I would really want to include the negative variances in model with R. Does anyone have any suggestions that what packages I would use? Or, does the new `lme4` allow it?

Comment: It would help a lot to explain *why* you want to do this ...

Answer (score 5):

New `lme4` doesn't allow it, nor does `nlme`.  It looks like [ASReml](https://www.vsni.co.uk/software/asreml/) might do it, if you set the IGU argument as described [here](http://www.vsni.co.uk/software/asreml/htmlhelp/asreml/vqual.htm) -- but ASReml is commercial, so you'd have to buy a license.

The more statistically sound way to deal with this situation is typically to fit a *compound symmetry* variance structure, which will allow negative correlations within groups.  You can do this via `nlme`, or in several somewhat more experimental frameworks (e.g. the "flexLambda" development branch of `lme4`).

More discussion from the mailing list [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q3/004202.html).