# Tests for Variance Components - mixed model

Tags: r, statistics, regression, mixed-models, nlme

See the following situation:

[image]

Ok, based on this, I have fitted the following models above in `R` (however, I am not sure if these models are right):

```
library(nlme)
model1 <- lm(Y ~ Treatm * VarT, data = datarats)
model2 <- lme(Y ~ Treatm * VarT, data = datarats, random = ~ 1|RAT, method = "ML")
model3 <- lme(Y ~ Treatm * VarT, data = datarats, random = list(RAT = pdDiag(~ VarT)), method = "ML")
model4 <- lme(Y ~ Treatm * VarT, data = datarats, random = ~ 1 + VarT | RAT, method = "ML")
```

Ok, now my interest is to do the test for variance components involving the following comparisons:

Model 2 vs. Model 1
Model 3 vs. Model 2
Model 4 vs. Model 2

See below the code:

```
library(varTestnlme)
library(EnvStats)
library(lmeInfo)
Comp1 <- varCompTest(model2, model1, pval.comp = "both")
summary(Comp1)
print.htestEnvStats(Comp1)
------
Comp2 <- varCompTest(model3, model2, pval.comp = "both")
summary(Comp2)
print.htestEnvStats(Comp2)
------
Comp3 <- varCompTest(model4, model2, pval.comp = "both")
summary(Comp3)
print.htestEnvStats(Comp3)
```

However, there is something wrong going on (I suspect it is in the specification of my model 4 - mainly).
Here's the thing: based on the results I would like to arrive at, the p-value involving the comparison between models 2 and 4 should be `p-value = 0.85`
`((1 - pchisq(0.1,1))/2 + (1 - pchisq(0.1,2))/2`, where 0.1 is the difference  between the loglik of both models).

See:

[image]

Therefore, when performing the test with the `varTestnlme package`, I am getting `p-value = 1`, i.e. models 2 and 4 are equal (difference between the `logLik()` of both models is equal to zero).
See the results:

```
summary(Comp3)
Variance components testing in mixed effects models
Testing that:
 variance of the random effect associated to VarT is equal to 0
against the alternative that:
 variance of the random effect associated to VarT > 0 

 Likelihood ratio test statistic:
    LRT =  -1.759843e-07

 Limiting distribution:
    mixture of 2 chi-bar-square distributions with degrees of freedom 1 2
    associated (exact) weights: 0.5 0.5

 p-value of the test:
    from exact weights: 1
```

I put below the results of the random effects covariance structure:

```
> VarCorr(model2)
RAT = pdLogChol(1) 
            Variance StdDev  
(Intercept) 3.289539 1.813709
Residual    1.423777 1.193221
> VarCorr(model4)
RAT = pdLogChol(1 + VarT) 
            Variance     StdDev      Corr  
(Intercept) 3.289539e+00 1.813708744 (Intr)
VarT        1.492819e-08 0.000122181 0     
Residual    1.423777e+00 1.193221261
```

In this topic: [Mixed effects model with negative variances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407631/mixed-effects-model-with-negative-variances) it is said that there is a limitation with the `nlme` package referring to negative variances in the model and see in the print above that the D matrix has a negative entry for the slope variation. However, in this same post: [Mixed effects model with negative variances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407631/mixed-effects-model-with-negative-variances) it is said that one of the ways to solve the problem is to consider the *compound symmetry variance structure*, which will allow negative correlations within groups. Therefore, I readjusted the models as follows:

```
model2 <- lme(Y ~ Treatm * VarT, data = datarats, random = ~ 1|RAT, 
              correlation = corSymm(form = ~1), 
              method = "ML")

model3 <- lme(Y ~ Treatm * VarT, data = datarats, random = list(RAT = pdDiag(~ VarT)), 
              correlation = corSymm(form = ~1), 
              control = lmeControl(opt = "optim", optCtrl = list(method = "BFGS")),
              method = "ML")

model4 <- lme(Y ~ Treatm * VarT, data = datarats, random = ~ 1 + VarT | RAT,
              correlation = corSymm(form = ~1), 
              control = lmeControl(opt = "optim", optCtrl = list(method = "BFGS")), 
              method = "ML")
```

See random effects covariance structure values:

```
> VarCorr(model2)
RAT = pdLogChol(1) 
            Variance StdDev  
(Intercept) 3.338813 1.827242
Residual    1.417336 1.190519
> VarCorr(model3)
RAT = pdDiag(VarT) 
            Variance    StdDev    
(Intercept) 3.370298164 1.83583718
VarT        0.001353776 0.03679369
Residual    1.384231329 1.17653361
> VarCorr(model4)
RAT = pdLogChol(1 + VarT) 
            Variance    StdDev     Corr  
(Intercept) 3.372970029 1.83656474 (Intr)
VarT        0.002481283 0.04981247 0.019 
Residual    1.375129804 1.17265929
```

However, the problem still persists. So I have a feeling that my models are not implemented correctly in `R`, based on the initial information in this post, since the resulting test values for variance components are not consistent with what they should be. Is there any way around this?

To exemplify, I am putting the same situation, however considering `Orthodont data` from `R`:

```
data(Orthodont)
library(nlme)
library(varTestnlme)
library(EnvStats)
library(lmeInfo)
model11 <- lm(distance ~ Sex * age, data = Orthodont)
model22 <- lme(distance ~ Sex * age, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1|Subject, 
              method = "ML")
model33 <- lme(distance ~ Sex * age, data = Orthodont, random = list(Subject = pdDiag(~ age)),
              method = "ML")
model44 <- lme(distance ~ Sex * age, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1 + age | Subject, 
              method = "ML")

Comp11 <- varCompTest(model22, model11, pval.comp = "both")
summary(Comp11)
print.htestEnvStats(Comp11)

Comp22 <- varCompTest(model33, model22, pval.comp = "both")
summary(Comp22)
print.htestEnvStats(Comp22)

Comp33 <- varCompTest(model44, model22, pval.comp = "both")
summary(Comp33)
print.htestEnvStats(Comp33)
```

Comment: As you can see from the Orthodont example data, the models are fitted correctly, so you do have the right commands. Have you examined e.g. `VarCorr(model2)` vs. `VarCorr(model4)` with your original data to verify the correct random effects covariance structure has been fitted?

Comment: I believe that there is something wrong with the fit of my models (or there is some specification missing based on the information described above in each model). See that in the print the ````logLike()```` difference is 0.1 and in my case it is resulting in 0 (that is, the models display the same ````logLike()```` values). Regarding ````VarCorr()```` from models 2 and 4, it is resulting in exactly the same thing (the difference is that in model 4 the value of Corr (Intr) is 0 (See the update I made to the post.). Considering the results, I'm not sure the models fit correctly.

Comment: Thanks for including the `VarCorr()` output. That confirms the correct structure has been fitted, but there is very little variance associated with the random slopes. I have just now noticed that the D matrix in your printout has a negative entry for the slope variance, which typically means there were issues in the numerical optimization routine. Where are those results from?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info.

But see that there is this mention: "The more statistically sound way to deal with this situation is typically to fit a compound symmetry variance structure, which will allow negative correlations within groups. You can do this via nlme". So I updated the post but the problem persists ;s

Comment: Where can I find `datarats` ?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(datarats)`? Google drive is blocked on my laptop.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent the data are available as supplementary material to [Verbeke and Molenberghs (2003)](https://doi.org/10.1111/1541-0420.00032) that OP is trying to replicate. Presumably they are not licensed to be redistributed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The models are specified correctly. However, your reference result contains negative estimates of the random slope variance component in models 3 and 4.

According to [this answer from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32407816/4550695) such models cannot be fitted with `nlme` or `lme4`. A [recent (June 2023) discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2023q2/030425.html) on the [R-sig-mixed-models](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mixed-models) mailing list did not identify any freely available R packages that are able to do so, either.

It seems you cannot easily replicate these results in R at present.